# Generate xml from c# class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I appreciate if someone could help me construct an XML in the following format:

```
<requests>
<row no="1">
<fl val="Subject">Add Records Demo</fl>
<fl val="ContactName">John</fl>
<fl val="ProductName">Customer Care</fl>
<fl val="Email">john@demo.com</fl>
<fl val="Phone">002200330044</fl>
</row>
</requests>
```

This is what I have got so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<request>
<row>
<Subject>Add Records Demo</Subject>
<ContactName>John</ContactName>
<ProductName>Customer Care</ProductName>
<Email>john@demo.com</Email>
<Phone>002200330044</Phone>
</row>
</request>
```

Here is the my code that I use to construct the xml

```
 List<ZohoVM> lzr = new List<ZohoVM>();
 lzr.Add(zvm);
 Request rp = new Request();
 rp.zohorow = lzr;
 XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
 ns.Add("", "");
 XmlSerializer xsdocument = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request));
 StringWriter sw = new Utf8StringWriter();
 string xml = "";
 using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
 {
    xsdocument.Serialize(writer, rp, ns);
    xml = sw.ToString();
 }
 return xml;
```

My Request class

```
[XmlRoot("request")]
public class Request
{
   public Request()
   {
      zohorow = new List<ZohoVM>();
   }
    [XmlElement("row")]
    public List<ZohoVM> zohorow { get; set; }
}
```

And my ZohoVm class

```
public class ZohoVM
{
   public string Subject { get; set; }
   public string ContactName { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public int Phone { get; set; }
}
```

What I really want is to have "fl value" within in the xml tags. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why use serialization instead of XmlDocument/Xdocument, since you care about the format very much?

Answer (score 0):

I fear the `XmlSerializer` is not as flexible as you wish. What you can do, though, is to extract an XML-Schema from your example XML which you want to achieve. Using the above, one can for example write the following schema:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="requests" type="Request"/>
  <xs:complexType name="RowFlag">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="val" use="optional"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Row">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="RowFlag" name="fl" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="no"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Request">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="Row" name="row"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Perhaps you can refine this schema according to your needs. Then, you can generate the classes that create this schema using xsd.exe with the `/classes` option. In the generated code, you can add convenience properties which you then have to mark with an `XmlIgnore`-attribute.